# Copy Multiple Files between libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online

When file explorer is used to copy multiple files between libraries is SPO smart enough to just move copy the files from within the SharePoint servers or do the files first download to the local machine and then upload them again to the target library?

Comment: I want to say it is dumb because it is using WebDAV to move the data around. I think Fiddler would help diagnose if it is pulling down a copy and uploading it.

Comment: indeed that is correct.  Using Content and Structure works in some cases.